# Apple Podcast feed not reading RSS pubDate

Tags: rss, podcast, pubdate

I set up a new RSS feed for a client that previously had an Apple Podcast Connect feed. I subscribed to my new RSS feed through Apple Podcasts and everything looked great. I thought it was time to update the RSS URL of their Apple Podcasts Feed to the new URL. In doing so, it lists all Episodes as having been published on the date/time that I updated the URL. It doesn't seem to have any understanding of the  data that I've made sure to format correctly according to Apple's specs.

Does anyone have any idea what more information I can include to help communicate my issues? Anyone have any idea how I can get the feed to respect the ? To confirm, I have the  formatted as Mon, 02 Oct 2023 18:12:42 -06:00

Comment: I've got the same issue as you.  Each item in my feed has it's own pubDate but it seems to be using the current date ( when subscribing to the feed url ) for all podcast publications.